# How we can get value of json code in jquery

Tags: json

I send data using ajax and return json code.How can I get each Name key's value. Below is my code :-

```
[{"Name":"Calendar","EmailTemplates":[],
"Href":"http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/1"},
{"Name":"Products","EmailTemplates":[],
"Href":"http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/2"},
{"Name":"Personal Events","EmailTemplates":[],
"Href":"http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/3"},
{"Name":"Health Tips","EmailTemplates":[],"Href":"http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/4"},
{"Name":"Financial Tips ","EmailTemplates":[],"Href":"http://amt-ars-d.sevenverbs.com/api/v1/emailtemplategroups/5"}]
```

I want this output :
calender
Procudt

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var x = eval(YourJsonInput);

for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
        var name = x[i].Name; //Here you get the name
        var link = x[i].Href; //Here you get the href
}
```